# Meaning of Vector Space over $\mathbb{R}$ being a Subspace of $\mathbb{R^R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, vector-spaces

$\mathscr{P(\mathbb{R})}$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

How are below sentences related and why?

> (1) $\mathscr{P(\mathbb{R})}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
>   
> (2) In other words, $\mathscr{P(\mathbb{R})}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^R}$, the vector space of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I am not able to connecting the dots, in part because I am not familiar with the notion that being a vectors space over a field can be equivalent to it being a subspace over something else. In general, how should I make sense of a vector space involving a set of functions? Can you provide some examples with real valued functions, transcendental function, polynomials, and the like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the set of real polynomials (with coefficient-wise addition and scalar multiplication) forms a vector space over $\Bbb R$: Sums and multiples of polynomials are again polynomials. This is $(1)$.

Every polynomial, i.e., every formal(!) expression of the form $a_0+a_1X+\ldots +a_nX^n$ for suitable $n\in\Bbb N$ and $a_0,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb R$ can be *interpreted* in a quite natural way as a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, namely the one sending $x\in \Bbb R$ to $a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$. This gives us a *map* from $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ to the set $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ of all functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. As it turns out, the sums and multiples (as defined above) of polynomials map to the corresponding sums and multiples of functions. In other words: Our map $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is a linear map, thus making the *image* of this map a subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. As the map we chose was *natural*, we can in fact identify $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ with its image and thus view $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ itself as a subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. This is what statement $(2)$ expresses.

**However,** it is not advisable to join the two statements with the phrase  "In other words".

For one, if $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$, it does not imply that there exists a linear injective map (let alone a natural one) from $V\to\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. For example $V$ might have much larger dimension.

Secondly, while it is the case for every field $F$, we have a natural linear map from from $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ (or more usually written $\Bbb F[X]$) to $\Bbb F^{\Bbb F}$ that - just as above - sends a polynomial to the map that maps each field element to the polynomial evaluated at that element, it is not in generally true that this linear map $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)\to \Bbb F^{\Bbb F}$ is injective, which means that we cannot view $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ as a subspace of $\Bbb F^{\Bbb F}$ in a natural way - in fact, not even in an "unnatural" way: It may happen that $\dim \mathcal P(\Bbb F)>\dim \Bbb F^{\Bbb F}$.

Comment: Hagen, thanks for the answer. I have few questions in your response that would help me gain clarity. The statement "our map ... is a linear map, thus making the image of this map a subspace of $\mathbb{R^R}$. Can you please elaborate this little further. I am not exactly sure when you say the map is natural. I understanding any polynomial is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as it takes a real number and spits out a real number. But there is this $n^{th}$ power thing which is as I understand an element of naturals. This thing is making it "linear" which I don't quite understand.

Comment: @FrankSwanton A priori, *polynomials* (pretty much just a bunch of coefficients with powers of some symbol $X$) should not be confused with *polynomial function*. For example, over the field $\Bbb F_2$ of two elements, the polynomials $X$ and $X^3+X^2+1$ are different, but define the same function $\Bbb F_2\to\Bbb F_2$. - Nevertheless, mapping a polynomial to its corresponding polynomial function is "natural" insofar, as it follows very closely the very definition of *polynomial ring* (in a formal setup), namely that $A[X]$ is a ring, together with [continued]

Comment: @FrankSwanton [continuation] an embedding $\iota\colon A\to A[X]$ such that for every ring $B$, ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ and element $b\in B$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $h\colon A[X]\to B$ such that $h(X)=b$ and $h\circ \iota=f$. - Yes, the polynomial functions themselves may not be linear functions. But the map that assigns to each polynomial its corresponding polynomial function *is* linear. This sounds fancier than it is. It just means that the way we add polynomials (coefficient-wise) is compatible with the way we add functions (point-wise).

Answer (score 1):

Some examples:

- the set of solutions of equation of the harmonic oscillator $\,y''+\omega^2y=0$, is  a real vector space of dimension $2$, with basis the functions $\{\cos \omega x,\sin\omega x\}$.
- The set of continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ is a vector space. It is not finite dimensional (as most function spaces)
- The set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf R[X]$, is a vector space with basis $\{1, X, X^,\dots, X^n,\dots\}$.
- The set of sequences which are solutions of  a linear recurrence equation, such as $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ (used to define *Fibonacci numbers*) is a vector space of dimension $2$. It is a subspace of the vector space of all infinite sequences.